# Appcache data also accessed when browser is online

Tags: html, browser-cache, html5-appcache, application-cache, manifest.cache

i am working on html5 application and i have a issue with appcache manifest file, that appcache's data accessed when browser is online and internet connection available,
But i want to access appcache's data when internet connection lost and browser is offline... 
this is my appcache file

demo.appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-02-21 v1.0.0
/Default.html
/App/Views/Lead.html
/Css/Main.css
/Css/bootstrap.min.css
/App/App.js
/Script/bootstrap.min.js
/Script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
/Script/angular.min.js
/Script/angular-resource.min.js
/Script/angular-route.min.js
/Script/angular-local-storage.min.js
/Script/jcs-auto-validate.min.js
/Script/loading-bar.min.js
/App/Service/authInterceptorService.js
/App/Service/authService.js
/App/Service/tokensManagerService.js
/App/Controller/DefaultController.js
/App/Controller/LeadController.js
/Images/Logo_original.png
/Images/arrow_left_grey.png
/Images/contactPerson.png
/Images/Password.png
/Images/ToggleOn.png
/Images/logout2_grey.png
/Images/arrow-left_green.png
/Images/checkbox_green.png
/Images/arrowRight_grey.png
NETWORK:
*
FALLBACK:
/html/ //Default.html
SETTINGS:
prefer-online
```

please give me hint if anyone have solution....